# Can we apply Euler's formula on plain waves?

Tags: waves, vectors, complex-numbers

I don't speak English so edit my question if it is not accurate.

Euler's formula for a complex number is:
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i \sin\theta$$
But when I write a plain wave as
$$e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}) + i \sin(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x})$$ I think something is not right because $\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}=kx\cos(\beta)$ that means we are taking the cosine of another cosine: Setting $kx=1$ we have $$e^{i\cos(\beta)}=\cos(\cos(\beta)) + i \sin(\cos(\beta))$$ which is a bit non-intuitive. So, I thought you may help me understanding $e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}$. Can we apply Euler's formula on plain waves? How did we extend an angle to a dot product?

Comment: Ok, but $\beta$ isn't a variable, it is the angle between the x-axis and the wave propagation direction.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $kx=1$ is probably what confuses you. If you go to a Cartesian frame you have $\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x} = k_x x + k_y y + k_z z$ which is a number. Let us call this number $\ell$. We then have
$$
e^{i\vec{k}\cdot \vec{x}}= e^{i\ell} = \cos \ell + i \sin \ell
$$
So your formula  is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: This $\ell$ is the phase difference
between position $\vec{0}$ and position $\vec{x}$.